# What is the upper limit on the numbers of requests to linkedin?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, linkedin-api, throttling

I want to scrape some data from linkedin and I used selenium in Python to login to linkedin and then get data from a page. I know linkedin is so sensitive to be scraped and uses anti-scrape to avoid it and block account and IP that request so fast or more times. I need to know what is the upper limit on the numbers of requests to linkedin to avoid being blocked.

Comment: they have an API:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authentication?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: @DebanjanB I want to do it as much as linkedin allows so need to know upper limit on numbers of requests to it.

Comment: @pcalkins I want data that linkedin API didn't provide.

Comment: You should probably ask linkedin... maybe post on their forum?:  https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks for the link to the [LinkedIn API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authentication?context=linkedin/consumer/context)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Throttle Limits](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1/throttle-limits) published by [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/):

> LinkedIn API keys are throttled by default. The throttles are designed
> to ensure maximum performance for all developers and to protect the
> user experience of all users on LinkedIn.
>
> There are three types of throttles applied to all API keys:
>
> - Application throttles: These throttles limit the number of each API call your application can make using its API key.
> - User throttles: These throttles limit the number of calls for any individual user of your application. User-level throttles serve
>   several purposes, but in general are implemented where there is a
>   significant potential impact to the user experience for LinkedIn
>   users.
> - Developer throttles: For people listed as developers on their API keys, they will see user throttles that are approximately four times
>   higher than the user throttles for most calls. This gives you extra
>   capacity to build and test your application. Be aware that the
>   developer throttles give you higher throttle limits as a developer of
>   your application. But your users will experience the User throttle
>   limits, which are lower. Take care to make sure that your application
>   functions correctly with the User throttle limits, not just for the
>   throttle limits for your usage as a developer.
>
> **Note**: To view current API usage of your application and to ensure you haven't hit any throttle limits, visit
> https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps and click on "Usage & Limits".

---

### Scraping LinkedIn using Selenium

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) the *throttle limit* would be further less as requests will start failing as soon as your program gets detected as a bot.

> **Note**: Scraping [*LinkedIn*](https://www.linkedin.com/) is against their [*TOS*](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/56347/prohibited-software-and-extensions?lang=en) and you risk having your accounts being restricted or shut down. Use [*LinkedIn API*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authentication?context=linkedin/consumer/context) instead.